# gnome-terminal: how to preserve symlinks of working directory when opening new tab?

Tags: linux, bash, gnome, gnome-terminal, bashrc

If I'm using `gnome-terminal` in a working directory whose path includes symlinks and I open a new tab, the symlinks will be expanded to their destinations in the working directory of the new tab.

Is there any way to preserve the symlinks when opening a new tab?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe with Ubuntu 10.04 and all default settings for gnome-terminal and bash. The problem may be a setting in your `.bashrc`; try moving it temporarily out of the way to check. If the problem persists, add more information, at least the versions of `gnome-terminal` and `bash`, and a detailed list of steps to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: I can reproduce it.  By "directory that includes symlinks" he means "working directory whose path includes symlinks".  Under `gnome-terminal` 2.30.2 and  `bash` 4.1.5: `mkdir -p foo/bar/baz; ln -s foo/bar/baz link; cd link` -- then create new tab -- then `pwd`.  It will report "foo/bar/baz" rather than "link".

Comment: @Jander, thanks, I'll edit to include your clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect there is no truly good answer to this.  `gnome-terminal` finds `bash`'s current working directory by inspecting `/proc/<pid>/cwd`, which has the symlinks expanded (probably for security reasons, if nothing else).  I don't know of another way for one process to find another process's working directory.

As a workaround, there are some bash tricks you could try, but see the **WARNING** below!  In .bashrc:

```
...
PROMPT_COMMAND='pwd >~/.bashlocal_saved_dir'
...

[ -n "$PS1" -a -f ~/.bashlocal_saved_dir ] && cd `cat ~/.bashlocal_saved_dir`
# end of .bashrc
```

This will do two things.  First, every time bash displays the prompt, it will first write its current working directory into the file `.bashlocal_saved_dir` in your home directory.  Second, when bash starts interactively (as opposed to running a script), it will change to the directory stored in that same file.  This means that when you start a new interactive bash, it will start in the same dir as the bash that last displayed its prompt.  Note that you can hit Enter to cause a bash to redisplay its prompt, thus making it the last. :)

**WARNING**: This is a hack, and I have only tried it up to the point that I know it works.  Think bubble gum and shoestrings.  It may have surprising effects, and will certainly not work as cleanly as `gnome-terminal`'s approach.  In particular, if you're running a lot of tabs at once, all doing background tasks, you may very well end up in the "wrong" directory when opening a new tab.

Comment: +1. But I think a safer solution, if one only has a few working dirs with symlinks, is check if you're in one of them, and call `cd` accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

This bug is being tracked on [Ubuntu Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/263637) and [GNOME Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=502146).

Since this mainly annoys me with only a few directories, I use the following simpler workaround.

Suppose you have `/home/username/work` as a symlink to `/long/path/named/asdf`. So you do `cd ~/work` in gnome-terminal, open a new tab, and find terminal reporting the full path. To fix this, just put the following in your `.bashrc`:

```
cd ${PWD/\/long\/path\/named\/asdf/$HOME\/work}
```

When gnome-terminal starts a new shell, it gets the current directory with $PWD, and if it contains `/long/path/named/asdf`, it replaces that string with `$HOME/work`, and `cd`s to the resulting string. If $PWD does not contain the string, it is equivalent to `cd $PWD`, which does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I love [@ShreevatsaR's answer](https://superuser.com/a/356247/58805).  Expanding it to signal when this is happening and to make it so I can undo with a quick `popd`, I'm using:

```
for sub in \
    "${PWD/\/home\/vus\/.cache\/vus\/build/\/vrepos\/build}" \
    "${PWD/\/home\/vus\/repos/\/vrepos}"
do
  if [ "$sub" != "${PWD}" ] ; then
     echo -n "pushd "
     pushd "$sub"
     break # prevents first pushd from tripping later checks
  fi
done
```

An example new window (with `PS1='#prompt# \[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00;35m\]$(__git_ps1)\[\033[00m\]\$ '`), including use of popd shows:

```
pushd /vrepos/build/2_dev_Ubuntu_Debug /home/vus/.cache/vus/build/2_dev_Ubuntu_Debug
#prompt# /vrepos/build/2_dev_Ubuntu_Debug$ popd
/home/vus/.cache/vus/build/2_dev_Ubuntu_Debug
#prompt# /home/vus/.cache/vus/build/2_dev_Ubuntu_Debug$
```

Answer (score -1):

Found this issue to be unresolved as of gnome-shell 3.14.4.

A workaround would be to use the bash Shell Variable SHLVL (which is incremented  by 1 every time bash is started) in .bashrc, as follows

```
# bash login shell would be at level 1.
[[ $SHLVL -eq 2 ]] && cd
```